# How to access Accessors value in withPivot() In Laravel - belongsToMany Relationship

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, relationship

I Have added one Accessor for Date formatting.

```php
public function getFormattedDateAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->review_date)->format('d M Y');
}
```

I want to access this field in with pivot Table

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function fileGuestReviewers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(GuestReviewer::class, 'stage_file_reviewers')
        ->withPivot(['status','formatted_date']);
}
```

Also, I already added this: `protected $appends = ['formatted_date'];`

Getting Error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stage_file_reviewers.formatted_date'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WithPivot()` deals with database columns, you have defined a mutator which is executed after the database query. Therefor you need to include the underlying property it is using.

Therefor changing this should help your problem.

```
->withPivot(['status','review_date']);
```

You would be able to access your field like so.

```
$model->fileGuestReviewers->first()->formattedDate;
```